# drawing NSString using drawRect and animate it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am drawing a NSString using drawRect and is it possible for me to animate this NSString once it has been drawn? I want it to fade in/out after 3.0 seconds. How can I do so?

Comment: How about using a `UILabel` and animate that over the view? Would that help?

Comment: drawRect is the bottom of the barrel. If you want to animate it then its up to you to set up the look and adjust your drawRect. You could use something like an NSTimer and adjust a property for opacity on your custom drawn string then mark the custom view as dirty in your timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a UILabel, then use animation to perform your desires

```
- (void)faceInLabel{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    label.text = @"My String";
    [myView addSubview:label];
    label.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        label.alpha = 1;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(fadeOutLabel) userInfo:nil   repeats:NO];
      }];
}
- (void)fadeOutLabel
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        label.alpha = 0;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly fade the drawn string itself. You can fade layers and you can fade views. Draw the string onto one of these and fade the layer or view. This is generally most easily done with a `UILabel` or `CATextLayer`, but you can draw onto your own layer and fade that if you prefer.